# Bold only the top and bottom borders of a div

Tags: css, layout, html, border

I would like to bold the border of a div.
My problem is that i need to bold only the top and bottom borders.

For example: if i have a div as a shape of a square it should look:

```
_______________





_______________
```

How can i do it in css?

Comment: Borders don't have BOLD. They are not text - they have WIDTHS.

Answer (score 8):

In CSS

```
border-top:3px solid #000;
border-bottom:3px solid #000;
```

and then if you want borders on left and right just make them 1 px instead of 3

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
border: 2px 0px 2px 0px #000;
```

*Edit:*
Quick explanation of border shorthand properties. The order of elements is `width style color`, where the width is in the order of `Top Left Bottom Right`. So in the above example it will set the top and bottom borders to 2px with the left and right being 0px. It will default the style of the border to solid and the color will be black. To create a dashed border on the left and right instead you would use:

```
border: 0px 2px 0px 2px dashed #000;
```

Comment: @j08691: I thought about it, but I think excluding it encourages anyone this might help to RTFM. A link to the M might not hurt though.

Comment: @j08691: Hah! In looking for an appropriate link, even w3c doesn't have an adequate explanation of the border shorthand. Perhaps an explanation is in order after all.

Comment: Yah I saw that, but if you read through it, it doesn't list the order in which the widths are determined.

Comment: Are you certain you can use both shorthand methods together? I just tried your code in jsFiddle and it's not setting the border properly. I thought you could only specify the width once with shorthand, and you'd have to add in another CSS 'border-width: 2px 1px 2px 1px;' to set different widths for each side? http://jsfiddle.net/aZeCz/3/

Comment: @spaceman817: That's how it is according to the spec, but I can see in your fiddle that it's not working as specified.

Answer (score 1):

Set the width of the bottom and top borders higher.

```
#element {
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with:

```
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
border-top: 2px solid black;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
```

For more info, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-top and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-bottom.